# "Voting fraud reversed" implies that the user did wrong, even though they didn't

Tags: discussion, status-completed, serial-voting

I understand that there's been a reputation clean-up over the past few days, and the reasons for it.

However, a valued member of the TeX.SX community, [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=reputation), on his reputation page, has an entry saying

> -4360 ... **Voting fraud reversed**

I'm not challenging the arithmetic, but the description is ***offensive***. Would someone please fix it!

Comment: This has also happened to [one of the top-ranked users on mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard?tab=reputation)

Comment: @Verbeia -220 is quite different from -4360. :)

Answer (score 21):

The message means that user was the **target** of [voting fraud](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/), not that they committed it.

I'm wide open to a clearer message here. Community (that's you!), please give me better copy to put there and we'll make it so.

**Update:** In the next build these items will read "Serial [up/down]voting reversed", this build will roll out in just a few minutes.

Comment: If I received 4360 rep that I shouldn't have, I wouldn't really feel like a 'target' :)

Comment: would "serial upvoting reversed" avoid implying a value judgement?

Comment: Nick, thank you. Where can I find out what "Voting fraud" actually means?

Comment: @awoodland The problem with both of this is that the subject is missing, so somebody might assume the subject is the user whom the history belongs to

Comment: @awoodland's suggestion is perfect IMO.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: Wait...you came in here complaining that something is offensive and you don't even know what it actually means?

Comment: @Bobby: Think about it for two minutes. I know what "Voting Fraud" means *in English*. That doesn't mean I have to know what it means in asp.net or any other StackExchangeSpeak. And *in English*, I find it offensive.

Comment: @Bobby: He was offended by what he *thought* it meant (which is very unclear). Aside: How the hell can *that* much rep be involved in "vote fraud" in one day?

Comment: @YiJiang'sProble_, would `Reversed sustained serial voting` alleviate the ambiguity?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: So, I guess you're one of the people who find the name "Braunf_ck" offensive, too? *And yes, I just bowed to that \*\*\*\* \*\*\*\*\*\*\* obfuscation of real names.* On a mere side note, I do not find that term "Vote fraud" offensive at all, though, that would be a discussion about personal preferences, I fear.

Comment: @Madmartigan: I think that's just a summary.

Comment: @Bobby: How can you not understand that someone could be offended by being randomly accused of involvement in "vote fraud"?

Comment: @Madmartigan: Maybe I have a too much "well, let's see first what's going on" and passive attitude. Just because somebody got rep removed doesn't necessary mean that the user was involved into that, though it does imply that, yes. But there are other possibilities, too. And until that I know what it was I assume nothing, but go with "whatever". Also, I don't think "randomly" fits in these cases.

Comment: @awoodland has a good suggestion for an alternative description. I'd refine it to "Reversed serial upvotes by other users". No intimation that the user that lost the rep had anything to do with creating the serial upvoting.

Comment: @Bobby: I'm sorry, I didn't want to get into a meta-argument; let me try to explain. First, I didn't know what constituted "vote fraud"; second I wasn't offended by it per se - after all, I've been to Florida --, but I was offended that it appeared to be attached to the name of a good friend who I know wouldn't do that.

Comment: The reason I asked "what does it mean" in the SX sense was in order to try and provide an alternate wording that wouldn't be misleading.

Comment: Brent's question was born from a chat conversation on TeX.StackExchange which originated from my remark that having so prominent a -4150 in rep was not very nice, particularly for the "voting fraud" wording. *I* know what it is about (it happened some months ago, actually), but my perception is that such a wording might be misleading for the unexperienced user that happens to look at rep pages. I don't like very much having such a big figure in my rep page, but can live with it. :) The new wording seems quite better.

Comment: It now reads "Serial upvoting reversed".  That still doesn't make it clear that egreg did nothing wrong.  And there's still a wacking great red line where there shouldn't be.