# Can serial voting reversal please deduct the rep on the same day that the voting happened?

Tags: feature-request, serial-voting

Yesterday, I got repcapped through a serial upvoter, and I fully expected the rep to be taken away again. What I dislike, however, is the fact that I got the rep deduction account for *today*, which leaves me with a big minus (and red bar) for today unless I amass atleast the same amount of rep through upvotes. When the serial upvoter "grants" you over 130 rep, this isn't easily possible if you're not willing to spend 5h answering questions *just to get the red bar neutralized*.

[image: Serial voting reversal]

As you can see, I really don't have to worry about the rep itself, but it does look quite bad and also doesn't make sense to me that I should be punished because somebody else had gone on a voting spree. I'd rather have the rep deducted from the 225 (however it got to that number...) rep of the day the voting happened.

[image: Rep Graph]

As you can see from the graph, there are quite some days were I'm rather inactive in answering questions and just hang out in the Lounge, and a serial voting reversal would just be bad on one of those days. [Note that the same happened to another one of the Loungers yesterday](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=5553166#5553166):

> @LuchianGrigore You're lucky. I got a big fat red bar on my graph because of it (It was -113, and I only collected 55, totalling -58).

So, bottom line, can we please have the rep removed on the same day (if not technically, atleast data-wise)?

Comment: I doubt anyone will care about one others reputation graph.

Comment: @juergend: But I care for mine! :)

Comment: @juergend: OCDers care for their own.

Comment: And could we please remove this 'serial upvoting reversed' crap as well? It's really not helpful. (Huh, but when one gets serial downvoted, moderators don't take action saying that 'it will be undone automatically' but in fact often it won't ...

Comment: Related: [Please hide “serial upvoting reversed” entries in the public reputation history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139080/please-hide-serial-upvoting-reversed-entries-in-the-public-reputation-history).

Comment: @H2CO3, if you're saying you want a different message, then see  Nick's answer at [“Voting fraud reversed” implies that the user did wrong, even though they didn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124222/voting-fraud-reversed-implies-that-the-user-did-wrong-even-though-they-didnt/124225#124225).

Comment: Shouldn't it also calculate changes on the day the voting happens, just to get correct calculations of the reputation cap? (Both for serial upvoting and downvoting.) Seems to me that deducting the 132 on the day it happened would give you a net score that is higher than when deducting it on another day?

Comment: @Arjan: I don't think that's needed. If anything, I think I'd actually get a lower net score out of this without recalculation, since superfluous votes don't generate rep when I reached the repcap from the serial upvoting.

Comment: I liked when they just didn't tell you why...and we just asked and answered questions.

Comment: But, @Xeo, you were capped on that day. So, some of the serial upvotes (or some other upvotes that came *after* the serial upvotes capped you) were not given to you on that day, but were still substracted at a later time? Or maybe the revoked 132 is just the part of the votes that you actually got repuation for. (Ah, makes sense, as otherwise upvotes will be +5 or +10 per vote, which cannot total to 132.)

Answer (score 10):

How horrible it used to be, when we were in grade school, and the teacher either put a `+` on our papers with a big fat smiley, or an upside down smiley on a paper with a lot of red `-1`'s littered throughout the page.

We're not in grade school anymore, and the red minuses don't indicate that we did a bad job. On Stack Overflow, the red minus just simply indicates factual information:  *Some unseen event occurred that resulted in a deduction of the reputation score.*

It's not a reflection of your contributions. The only thing that matters is your *current* reputation score, how great your questions and answers are, and how helpful you are to the community.

Don't get hung up on *when* the reputation is added back or removed. It just doesn't matter, and you really shouldn't let it bother you. Obviously, if you're exceeding the rep cap as much as the graph shows, your contributions definitely speak for themselves. :)